# OnMouseMove without object inspector delphi

Tags: delphi, onmousemove

my application has 350 edit fields and all of them shall have an OnMouseMove event.
I have generated this code for all of them:

```
...

type

...    
procedure Edit1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
procedure Edit2MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);    
...

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

...    
procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,  
  Y: Integer);  
begin 
  Edit1.SetFocus(); 
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,  
  Y: Integer);
begin 
  Edit2.SetFocus(); 
end;    
...
```

But I didn't go to the object inspector to doubleclick OnMouseMove.
Is there a way to make this work without the object inspector.
Do you have an example line of code that would make it work for the first edit field?

Comment: 350 edit fields on the same form? Have you considered using a gird?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create it once and assign it in code yourself:

```
type
  TForm1=class(TForm)
    procedure EditMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    //...
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.EditMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var
  CurrEdit: TEdit;
begin
  if (Sender is TEdit) then
  begin
    CurrEdit := TEdit(Sender);
    // Do whatever with CurrEdit
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.OnMouseMove := EditMouseMove;
  Edit2.OnMouseMove := EditMouseMove;
  Edit3.OnMouseMove := EditMouseMove;
end;
```

If you want to assign the same one to every `TEdit` on the form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    if Controls[i] is TEdit then
      TEdit(Controls[i]).OnMouseMove := EditMouseMove;
end;
```

Comment: this is pure magic and saved us a lot of hard work, thank you

Comment: @MichaelMoeller: not to diminish Ken's answer, but this isn't magic at all, this is knowing the language and the IDE that you are working in. An attitude of "this shouldn't be so much hard work, there ought to be an easier way" and investigating/googling that goes a long way to acquiring that knowledge.

Comment: Or Ken will write it for ya. :-)